# Qt image format plugins

Tags: image, qt, qt4, qimage

Can somebody point me to sites with not supported by Qt image format plugins (reading/writing). XCF and PSD for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a plugin which uses the DevIL image library to support a variety of formats:

http://tcuvelier.developpez.com/qt/extend/devil/

Answer (score 3):

dds, eps, exr, g3r, hdr,jp2, pcs, pg, pns, psd, ras, rgb, tga, xcf qimage plugins are provided by KDE in the kdelibs/kimgio directory.

Answer (score 1):

There was an app called Pixie in the early days of KDE, perhaps you can find something there. Otherwise, I'd suggest looking at what the GIMP does.

Answer (score -6):

Well, here you have a list of all the formats QT 4.6 QImage support:

> BMP Windows Bitmap Read/write
>
> GIF Graphic Interchange Format (optional) Read
>
> JPG Joint Photographic Experts Group Read/write
>
> JPEG Joint Photographic Experts Group Read/write
>
> PNG Portable Network Graphics Read/write PBM
>
> Portable Bitmap Read
>
> PGM Portable Graymap Read
>
> PPM Portable Pixmap Read/write
>
> TIFF Tagged Image File Format Read/write
>
> XBM X11 Bitmap Read/write
>
> XPM X11 Pixmap Read/write

And here you can see all the images available everywhere. Tons of them. Like a hundred:

[Wikipedia. Comparison of Graphics File Formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_graphics_file_formats)

And the popular:

JPEG · JPEG 2000 · JPEG XR · lossless JPEG · JBIG · JBIG2 · PNG · WBMP

APNG · BMP · DjVu · EXR · GIF · ICER · ILBM · MNG · PCX · PGF · TGA · TIFF